# use regex to replace spaces that occur with a value depending on how many spaces found

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use a regex that looks for spaces with a minimum length of 2 in a row, and replaces the occurrence with another value for each occurrence of the space found.

For example:

```
I love   to eat    cake
```

There are 3 spaces after love and 4 spaces after eat. I want my regex to replace occurrences of a space more than 1, and to replace it with a value for each occurrence found.

The output I am trying to go for:

```
I love---to eat----cake
```

I tried something like

```
myStr.replace(/ +{2,}/g, '-')
```

Comment: javascript, but if you have a solution in Python I can understand that as well. Or even regex101. I want to understand how the regex works.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this code with a lookahead and a lookbehind:

```js
const s = 'I love   to eat    cake'

var r = s.replace(/ (?= )|(?<= ) /g, '-');

console.log(r);
//=> 'I love---to eat----cake'
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?= )`: Match a space only if that is followed by a space
- `|`: OR
- `(?<= )` : Match a space only if that is preceded by a space

Comment: Could you maybe add a quick explanation as to what is going on?

Comment: I have added some explanation in my answer. Feel free to ask any query/doubt about the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can match two or more whitespaces and replace with the same amount of hyphens:

```js
const s = 'I love   to eat    cake'
console.log(s.replace(/\s{2,}/g, (x) => '-'.repeat(x.length)) )
```

The same approach can be used in Python (since [you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007815/use-regex-to-replace-spaces-that-occur-with-a-value-depending-on-how-many-spaces/70008022#comment123754280_70007815)), `re.sub(r'\s{2,}', lambda x: '-' * len(x.group()), s)`, see [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/2ydAKk).

Also, you may replace any whitespace that is followed with a whitespace char or is preceded with whitespace using

```js
const s = 'I love   to eat    cake'
console.log(s.replace(/\s(?=\s|(?<=\s.))/gs, '-') )
console.log(s.replace(/\s(?=\s|(?<=\s\s))/g, '-') )
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NDLuGR/2). Here, `s` flag makes `.` match any char. `g` makes the regex replace all occurrences. Also,

- `\s` - matches any whitespace
- `(?=\s|(?<=\s.))` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a whitespace char (`\s`), or (`|`) if it is immediately preceded with a whitespace and any one char (which is the matched whitespace). If you use `(?<=\s\s)` version, there is no need of `s` flag, `\s\s` just makes sure the whitespace before the matched whitespace is checked.